# Filling a 2d array with contents from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, average

I have a file that is formatted as follows:

```
Name|Test1|Test2|Test3|Test4|Test5|Test6|Test7|Test8|Test9|Test10   
John Smith|82|89|90|78|89|96|75|88|90|96
Jane Doe|90|92|93|90|89|84|97|91|87|91
Joseph Cruz|68|74|78|81|79|86|80|81|82|87
Suzanne Nguyen|79|83|85|89|81|79|86|92|87|88
Richard Perez|100|84|73|81|92|84|95|96|95|100
Ivan Dyer|77|91|90|75|97|94|76|89|90|92
Craig Palmer|91|84|98|89|82|75|78|96|100|97
Madeline Rogers|75|79|78|93|91|76|80|88|100|81
Chelsea Roxas|87|94|89|96|95|85|88|92|86|86
Jasper Bautista|100|83|93|100|98|97|96|97|97|98
```

I have created an ArrayList that is populated left to right with the integers from the table above. I confirmed that all the numbers are in the ArrayList. What I am trying to accomplish is getting the average of the columns, so I thought that using a 2d array is doable, but I am having a hard time figuring out the correct for-loop syntax to properly fill the array.

If anyone has any other solution apart from mine or would like to help me out, I would really appreciate it!

Edit: I have tried the following:

```
int len = tests.length;
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
      {tests[i][0] = (Double) testScores.get(i);
       tests[0][j] = (Double) testScores.get(j);
      }
    }
```

Which yields this output:

```
[[82.0, 89.0, 90.0, 78.0, 89.0, 96.0, 75.0, 88.0, 90.0, 96.0], [89.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [78.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [89.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [96.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [75.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [88.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [96.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] showing what you have tried in order to achieve your goal so we can help you find out why it doesn't work and how to fix it. Tip: a 2d array has two indexes, to add all the values of a column you increment the row index but leave the column index unchanged. To add all values by column you increment the column index only after you're done iterating through all the rows of that column.

Comment: I edited my post to show what I've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i <10  ; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <10  ; j++){
      {tests[i][j] = (Double) testScores.get(i*10 +j);
      }
    }
```

this will work

if you want to calculate the mean of the i-th column :

```
double mean(column_index) {
    double mean = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <10  ; i++){
        mean = mean + tests[i][column_index];}
    return (mean/10) ;}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! Do you maybe know how I could go about adding up the columns and getting the mean?

Comment: consider upvoting my answer if this was useful

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: and I edited my post to show you how to calculate the mean

Comment: @NRMA if you appeciate Adriens help you should consider acceping this answer (There should be a button for you as the asker)

Comment: Done! Sorry I just started using StackOverflow and am not sure how things work. Thank you for reminding me!